# Excel VBA macro's using If then

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

i have no programming experience, but i recorded a macro that does the following:

```
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DataRaw").Select
    Range("Table3[[#Headers],[Datum]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Transactie").Select
    Range("C8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DataRaw").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Transactie").Select
    Range("D8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DataRaw").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Transactie").Select
    Range("D8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C8").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
```

when activated it moves values from selected cells to a table in another sheet. what i want is to be able do is have multiple tables of different categories and have the code recognise which categories my inputs belong to so that it can move the values to its respective table.

so that when i enter a fruit name, all the values would go to the fruits table and when i have a vegetable name, all the values would go to the veggie table. im guessing i need to use if, then statements but i just dont know how :S

hope my question is clear. thanks a lot!

Comment: Questions asking for code *must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved*. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: Take a look at pivot tables.  You can have your main data and then on a different sheet create a pivot table to show what every relationship you want for that data.  You can have many different tables pointing back to the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If-Then and VBA appears overly complicated for what you're attempting as the question is posed - suggest looking into pivot tables. Here's two links to get you started:

Essentials of Excel 2010 Pivot Tables and Pivot Charts - For Dummies
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-essentials-of-excel-2010-pivot-tables-and-pivo.html

Create or delete a PivotTable or PivotChart report - Excel - Office.com
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010089893.aspx

Comment: Bare links are not answers :) This should ideally be a comment as @PortlandRunner did above